# Django forms : how to use Html and css template forms

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I use (Html+CSS Template forms ) in django ?

Hi Guys. I really don't like django forms appearances or even crispy_forms so I  downloaded a form Html and Css from this website "colorlib.com" and  pasted in my 'signup.html', and 'signup.css' ,form showed up but after filling form and sending it, it shows error . I use CBVs .... I'm sure view and url are correct but I think I have to  change tags in html to django Tags, Thank you in advance :Btw I use bootstrap , do i need change its href

This is form template in django which is very simple and I need more beautiful one :

```
<!-- templates/signup.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
   form_class = UserCreationForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
   template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Html of form (https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/aaaoVJ) which i like to use

```
 <!--
Author: Colorlib
Author URL: https://colorlib.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Creative Colorlib SignUp Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- web font -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //web font -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main -->
    <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
        <h1>Creative SignUp Form</h1>
        <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
                    <div class="wthree-text">
                        <label class="anim">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required="">
                            <span>I Agree To The Terms & Conditions</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="#"> Login Now!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- copyright -->
        <div class="colorlibcopy-agile">
            <p>© 2018 Colorlib Signup Form. All rights reserved | Design by <a href="https://colorlib.com/" target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- //copyright -->
        <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- //main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Guys, I really appreciate that  if you can explain for me  . Thank you

Comment: what is the error?